# Rust generics - traits, structs and associated types

Tags: generics, rust

I am from C++ community, switching to Rust... and playing with Rust generics, can anyone please explain why I am getting this error in this dummy example?

```
struct FF<T1, T2>(T1, T2);

trait FFt<T1, T2> {
    type t1 = T1;
    type t2 = T2;
    fn call<t1, t2>(&self, t_1: Self::t1, t_2: Self::t2);
};

impl<T1, T2> FFt<T1, T2> for FF<T1, T1> {
    fn call<T1, T2>(&self, t_1: Self::t1, t_2: Self::t2) {
        t_1.a = 1;
        t_2.b = 1;
    }
}

struct AA {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
let fff: FF<AA, AA> = FF(AA { a: 0, b: 0 }, AA { a: 0, b: 0 });

fff.call(AA { a: 0, b: 0 }, AA { a: 0, b: 0 }); // <----- ERROR LINE !!!
```

Error:

```
error[E0609]: no field `a` on type `T1`
   --> p2p/./src/lib.rs:172:17
    |
170 |     impl<T1,T2> FFt<T1,T2> for FF<T1,T1> {
    |          -- type parameter 'T1' declared here
171 |         fn call<T1,T2>(&self,t_1 : Self::t1,t_2 : Self::t2) {
172 |             t_1.a = 1;
    |                 ^

error[E0609]: no field `b` on type `T2`
   --> p2p/./src/lib.rs:173:17
    |
170 |     impl<T1,T2> FFt<T1,T2> for FF<T1,T1> {
    |             -- type parameter 'T2' declared here
...
173 |             t_2.b = 1;
    |                 ^
```

Comment: Because T1, T2 types in `FFt` type are placeholder for any type. It's not known that `a` or `b` fields will really exist for concrete types. For example, what if I make a type `FF<u32, u32>`.

Comment: Imagine you did `let fff: FF<i32, i32> = FF(1, 2); fff.call(3, 4);` There is no `1.a` of `4.b` to access. If you need access to specific fields of a struct, you either need to bound the generic type by a trait that exposes that field through a method, or not use generics but instead the specific type want to use.

Comment: Rust behaves differently to C++ in this regard: C++ allows you to "just go and see how far you get", basically duck-typing and see if the template arguments have a member `a` or not. Rust, on the other hand, requires you to specify what you want to do with your generic types. AFAIK there's no way to specify that the types will have a member `a` - instead you'll probably want to have a trait that possibly has `fn a() -> i32` and then call `a()` where you'd in C++ simply access member `a`.

Comment: @phimuemue You need `set_a()` or `a_mut()`, but apart from that you're right.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to read the rust book, because you're off to a not-great start.

> can anyone please explain why I am getting this error in this dummy example ?

Because C++ generics and Rust generics work off of completely different principles.

C++ templates will be type-substituted then checked, so as long as you pass a type which fits into what's being used it'll work.

Rust generics are based around *constraints*, they are typechecked independent of instantiation, and work solely off of what the constraints allow. Constraints are specified trough *traits*. I've heard C++ *Concepts* work similarly though I've no experience there.

Here, your generic types are unconstrained, so as far as the compiler is concerned they're *incapable*, the compiler will pretty much only assume that they're `Sized`. Furthermore, traits don't support fields.

Also

```rust
trait FFt<T1,T2>{
        type t1 = T1;
        type t2 = T2;
```

this doesn't make much sense, the point of a generic type parameter is that the *caller* decides what it is, the point of an associated type is that the *implementor* decides what it is (but there can be only one per implementation).

And then

```rust
        fn call<t1,t2>(&self, Self::t1, Self::t2);
```

This means `call` has two generic parameters `t1` and `t2` (incorrect naming conventions), which are also unconstrained, and completely independent from both `T1`/`T2` and `FFt::t1`/`FFt::t2`. So you've got 6 different unknown, unconstrained, and unrelated types at this point.

Comment: C++ concepts are similar to trait constraints, but are intended mainly for better errors: if the constraints aren't enough, C++ still uses duck typing.